# sed replace entire line with a string using simple regex check

Tags: sed

Im using cordova to build an app for android but cannot set the android:minSdkVersion in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

So i decided to modify this file each time i start building the app with a script i wrote.

I want to change the line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

to this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Since cordova does not allow me to set this using the config.xml (only phonegap build allows, but i use cordova only) i need to modify the xml on my own.

I would like to replace whats inside mindSdkVersion to 14.

How can i do that?

I tried this:

```
sed 's/minSdkVersion="(.*)"/minSdkVersion="14"/g' AndroidManifest.xml
```

but it still gives me the uses-sdk line unchanged.

Whats wrong with my regexp?

Comment: Note that `sed '...' file` will output the result of the command. If you want the file to be updated, use `sed -i.bak '...' file`. `file` will contain the new content, while `file.bak` will contain a backup.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. You need to modifily the group by replacing `(.*)` with `\(.*\)`
2. You don't need the group.
3. You match too much, try

   `sed 's/minSdkVersion="[0-9]+"/minSdkVersion="14"/g' AndroidManifest.xml`

If you want to modify the file, use `-i` to change the file.

Comment: It works with the gnu-sed in Ubuntu, what do you use?

Comment: @NovumCoder correct, `+` is an ERE metacharacter and sed uses BREs by default. You need to provide an arg to activate EREs (e.g. `-r` or apparently `-E`) or in some seds just putting a backslash before the `+` will be enugh to tell sed to use it as an ERE metacharacter instead of a literal plus sign.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your regex.

1. The parentheses are apparently interpreted as literal parentheses by your `sed` dialect. They are useless anyway, so you don't need to fix that -- just remove them.
2. `.*` is greedy and would match up to just before the *last* double quote.

With these remarks, the fix is easy.

```
sed 's/minSdkVersion="[^"]*"/minSdkVersion="14"/g' AndroidManifest.xml
```